# Progress Bar on File Browsing without Ajax in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

- I've browsing a large file, so I want to show the file browsing
  progress bar.
- I do not need to use ajax,
- I just want to show the progress bar and progress percentage when
  browsing or dragging the file from the browser.

**But unfortunately i didn't get a reference without ajax that's why i just posting here**

> sample code

```
  function uploadFile() {
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "index.php"); 
    ajax.send(formdata);
  }

 function progressHandler(event) {
   _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + 
   event.total;
   var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
 }


function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0; //wil clear progress bar after successful upload
}



   <div class="col-md-6">                               
       <label class="lbl mandatory" for="">Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
       <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"> 
       </progress>
          <h3 id="status"></h3>
        <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
   </div>
```

Comment: `I do not need to use ajax` so, how will you upload the file? that's why AJAX exists. Of course, you could just use a `<FORM>` but that won't show progress

Comment: i just want show the progress bar of browsing . file upload that i will do by manual submit

Comment: sure, so, that would be an ajax post request - but you don't want to use ajax ... see, the problem is, that the only way to do what you want is the only way you don't want to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot handle this without Ajax.
You can easily handle progress percentage with Dropzone.js